# Flutter Save JSON Array to SharedPreferences

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

How to save JSON array into SharedPreferences?

I've tried some code like this below, but i got some error :

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: type
> 'Text' is not a subtype of type 'String'

```
for (var x = 0; x < dynamicwidget.length - 1; x++) {
  _listOrder={
    "id_product": dataJSON[x]["product_id"],
    "order_count": dynamicwidget[x].controller.text,
  };
}

String json = jsonEncode(_listOrder);

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString(categoryname, json);
```

Comment: replace this dynamicwidget[x].controller.text with dynamicwidget[x].controller.text.toString()

Comment: Tks for your answer, but still not working

Comment: I think problem lies in this line only

Comment: instead of doing like this save order_count value in a variable and then assign it here

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use something like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage) (local storage implementation) which is made for saving and loading JSON.

From the code snippet itself i can't tell you exactly what is causing this exception but basically everywhere a `String` is beeing expected but you provided an actual `Text` widget. It could be the `categoryname` variable. What kind of `controller` do you get from your `dynamicWidget` instance? Are you sure `controller.text` returns a `String`?

Another note: you are re-assigning `_listOrder` with every for loop instead of adding information. You have to use an empty `array` which will be filled with every loop.

Comment: Noted, Thank for you reference

Comment: this library is legacy as it doesn't support null safety

Comment: As of version 4.0.0+1 it has been made null safe and can therefore be used as usual

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, for contributing this question.
I've solved this question and makes some change.

```
_listOrder.clear();
    for (var x = 0; x < dynamicwidget.length; x++) {
      int jml = int.parse(dynamicwidget[x].controller.text == ""? "0": dynamicwidget[x].controller.text);
      if (jml > 0) {
        _listOrder.add({
          "id_product": dataJSON[x]["product_id"],
          "order_count": dynamicwidget[x].controller.text,
        });
      }
    }

    if (_listOrder.length > 0) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      Map<String, dynamic> _collOrder = Map<String, dynamic>();
      String sessjson = prefs.getString("orderlist");
      if (sessjson != null) {
        _collOrder = json.decode(sessjson);
        _collOrder.remove(categoryname);
      }
      _collOrder[categoryname] = _listOrder;
      prefs.setString("orderlist", json.encode(_collOrder));
    }
```