# List of booleans in Shared Preferences Flutter

Tags: string, flutter, dart, boolean, sharedpreferences

Is there a way I can have a list of bools in shared preferences. I have a list of settings with checkboxes and I want to save those settings through multiple sessions. For that, I need to save a list of bool values. What is the best way to set and get a list of booleans.

Comment: You can only save ```List<String>``` in shared preferences. You can do is save ```bool``` as ```String``` and then convert it back to ```bool```. For  converting bool to String you can check https://pub.dev/documentation/string_validator/latest/string_validator/toBoolean.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `setStringList` with a list of `"0"` for false and `"1"` for true. The shared_preferences documentation shows that there is a `setBool` but no `setListBool`. https://pub.dev/documentation/shared_preferences/latest/shared_preferences/SharedPreferences-class.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use just a list of booleans then the list will look like [true, true, false, false, false, true]. You'll have to make another list of checkboxes and marry these two guys to get or set.

The better idea is to prepare a list of objects. Each object is a pair of your checkbox value and the status (true/false or checked/unchecked).
An alternative is to prepare a JSON and get/set JSON from the shared preference.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122176/1367159) answer on Stackoverflow shows how to get JSON array in the sharedprefs. The set, as you can guess is quite similar.